# Laravel/PHP: Conditional Date Filter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data back between two dates. However, these params are optional so we might get one or the other, both or neither.

I have the follow code so far, but I'm not getting any information back. Would anyone know where I'm messing up?

```
    public function getAnalyticsData(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $data = collect();

        $dataType = $request->input('data-type');
        $suppliers = $request->input('suppliers');
        $workgroupId = $request->input('workgroup-id');
        $costs = $request->input('costs');

        if ($dataType === 'orders') {
            $ordersData = [];
            foreach ($user->workgroups as $workgroup) {
                if ($workgroup->id == $workgroupId) {
                    array_push($ordersData, collect($workgroup->analyticsOrders));
                }
            }

            if ($request->filled('start-date') && $request->filled('end-date')) {
                $ordersData = collect($ordersData)
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', $request->input('start-date'))
                    ->where('created_at', '<=', $request->input('end-date'));
            } else if ($request->filled('start-date') || $request->filled('end-date')) {
                if ($request->filled('start-date')) {
                    $ordersData = collect($ordersData)->where('created_at', '>=', $request->input('start-date'));
                };

                if ($request->filled('end-date')) {
                    $ordersData = collect($ordersData)->where('created_at', '<=', $request->input('end-date'));
                }
            }

            $data->put('analyticsData', $ordersData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is overly complex, you are unpacking and packing collections to much. Just to get the basics down. Querying your data and doing collection logic with `collect()`, is not interchangeable. They have different performance and logic.

Start by creating your query builder. I assumed your relation structure, pretty hard to understand based on to many conditions. Add conditional queries with `when()`, first parameter is condition second is the query, will not execute unless condition is true.

```
$startDate = $request->input('start-date');
$endDate = $request->input('end-date');

$workgroups = AnalyticsOrder::where('workgroup_id', $workgroupId)
   ->whereHas('workgroup', function ($query) use ($user) {
       $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
   })->when($startDate, function ($query) use ($startDate) {
       $query->where('created_at', '>=', $startDate);
   })->when($endDate, function ($query) use ( $endDate) {
       $query->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate);
   })->get();
```

You have some other parts to your logic, you have not really included, this is just a much straight forward approach with around 10 lines. Then add whatever you need on top of that.